# How to force reserve() to use a non-default constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have the following code snippet:

```
MyType::MyType();            // size of MyType.aMember is a default size
MyType::MyType(int mySize);  // size of MyType.aMember depends on mySize
...
...
std::vector<MyType> myTypeVector;
myTypeVector.reserve(numberOfObjects);  // memory reserved is numberOfObjects * sizeof(MyType)
...
```

How can one make reserve not use the default constructor to determine the size of the individual objects, but use a desired constructor instead?

One can try the following:

```
MyType::MyType();            // size of MyType.aMember is a default size
MyType::MyType(int mySize);  // size of MyType.aMember depends on mySize
...
...
std::vector<MyType> myTypeVector(numberOfObjects, MyType(desiredSize));  // memory allocated is numberOfObjects * sizeof(MyType(desiredSize))
...
```

But the above calls the copy constructor which I would like to avoid for efficiency reasons. Hence my question.

Comment: Why would one need a constructor to know the size, isn't `sizeof` adequate?

Comment: `reserve` shouldn't use the default-constructor, because it doesn't *construct* anything, it just allocates.

Comment: `reserve()` doesn't construct any items anyway, but reserves space.

Comment: Your part `size of MyType.aMember depends on mySize` is not possible, so question does not make sense.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something. `MyType` can't change it's size. It just can't. Maybe you have a pointer or a container in `MyType` that does allocate memory based on `mySize`, but that doesn't change the size of `MyType`. Also `reserve` does not call any constructor, it just allocates memory.

Comment: Why is that not possible? I have `aMember.reserve(mySize)` in the constructor code.

Comment: I don't get how an object can have different size depending on the constructor ... Can someone explain that ?

Comment: `aMember.reserve(mySize)` reserves a separate block of memory that `aMember` then points at. That has no effect whatsoever on the size of memory needed to hold a `MyType` object. Its size is determined at compile-time, not run-time (`sizeof(MyType)` is constant), regardless of what `aMember` does at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type can only have exactly one size. Calling a non-default constructor has no effect on the size of the object. As such, there is no need for what you're asking. `reserve` does not and can not use a constructor to determine the size of the objects.

Your attempt `std::vector<MyType> myTypeVector(numberOfObjects, MyType(desiredSize));` does something wholly different. It *constructs* `numberOfObjects` number *copies* of a temporary `MyType` object and therefore must copy. If you wanted to simply reserve the space for those objects, then `myTypeVector.reserve(numberOfObjects);` would allocate exactly the correct amount of memory.

A vector does not contain objects inside itself. If it did, it could never change size. Instead, vector contains pointer(s) to a buffer which is allocated separately. Therefore, the capacity or object count of the vector has no effect on the size of the vector object itself and therefore they also have no effect on the size of an object that contains a vector member.

You cannot `reserve` memory for a the buffer of vector that doesn't exist. As I said, `myTypeVector.reserve(numberOfObjects);` is sufficient to allocate memory for your `MyType` instances and once the instances have been constructed, you can reserve space for the member vectors.

Comment: Sorry if my question did not make my need clear: I would like to reserve enough memory to hold the desired number of objects, each alike, but with a specific memory requirement of their own.

Comment: Could you rephrase that? Do you mean that you want to store objects of different types in the vector?

Comment: @ChandraMouli: `reserve()` merely reserves a block of memory that is large enough to hold N number of objects. It does not construct any objects inside that memory. You need to use the `push_...()` or `resize()` method to do that. So it does not matter what constructors are defined for `MyType`, `reserve()` will not call any of them. The memory requirements of the object's members are irrelevant to `reserve()`.

Comment: I may be using a wrong pattern, but here's what I would like to do: Reserve the space for a vector of objects, where each object is of the same type, but a member, which happens to be another vector, have a certain desired space reserved for itself.

Comment: Ah, now this is getting a bit clearer. You cannot reserve space for vectors that don't exist yet. You can only reserve memory `myTypeVector` and once you've constructed the `MyType` instances, you can then reserve the memory for the each member vector that now exist.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `reserve()` needs to know the size of the object, which in turn depends on the size of its members. If I need to also reserve for a member, such that a call to `emplace_back()` with a value for the vector member already has reserved space for itself, I'm not sure how I can achieve that.

Comment: "*`reserve()` needs to know the size of the object, which in turn depends on the size of its members.*" That is true. But you are confusing the fact that the size of `MyType::aMember` itself versus the size of the data that `MyType::aMember` refers to internally are **two different things**. The data that `MyType::aMember` refers to is dynamically allocated at run-time and is *irrelevant* to the size needed to reserve a `vector` of `MyType` objects, as that data is not part of `MyType` itself. It is external to `MyType`, allocated elsewhere in memory where only `MyType::aMember` knows.